# Get the Difference between Datetime in terms of hours with two round off set to 2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

Get difference between two datetime in terms of hours by rounding off to 2 decimal points

```
> `Started                     Ended`                     Hours
   2020-10-01 09:29:20         2020-10-01 17:43:28         8.2
   2020-10-31 09:26:43         2020-10-31 18:57:40         9.5
   2020-10-31 09:18:57         2020-10-31 21:06:30         11.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), last divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) and use [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df['Started'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Started'])
df['Ended'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Ended'])

df['new'] = df['Ended'].sub(df['Started']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600).round(2)
print (df)
              Started               Ended  Hours    new
0 2020-10-01 09:29:20 2020-10-01 17:43:28    8.2   8.24
1 2020-10-31 09:26:43 2020-10-31 18:57:40    9.5   9.52
2 2020-10-31 09:18:57 2020-10-31 21:06:30   11.8  11.79
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

```
from datetime import datetime
beg = '08:00:10'
end = '17:16:24' 

print('end = ',end, 'type: ',type(end))

dur = datetime.strptime(end, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(beg, '%H:%M:%S')

result = dur.total_seconds()/3600

result = round(result, 2)

print(result)
```